# Koala - Create tab in facebook (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, tabs, koala

I want to create tabs on FB.

I have this code:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(Client.find(session[:id_client]).oauth_token)
@graph.put_connections("4154829881847172/tabs","POST", {:access_token => "AAABwdtYjsyoBAMcg558a4FYnZBkZBUiPKmcWWssssWoNZC2yjqE43ghoR9uTiFIhT3ErkQYx45RrrPeOD0ZCvFgnmRIUh9lqRUw5KIlWwxtRW3GvbIEUWp0yB2", :app_id => '1236553701115690'})
```

But I have a problem

-> OAuthException: (#210) Subject must be a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 4154829881847172 the correct ID for the page you're trying to add the tab to? 
And are you definitely using the page's access token?  (as opposed to a user access token for the page admin)

Either of those being incorrect means you're passing a something-other-than-a-page's ID in place of the Page ID

Comment: ok,

    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(TOKEN_USER)
    @graph.put_connections("PAGE_ID/tabs","POST", {:app_id => 'APP_ID', :access_token => "TOKEN_PAGE"})
 

so it has to be?

Comment: I'm not sure how the syntax looks with Koala, but yes - you need to use the page's access token you got from the `/me/accounts` endpoint

Comment: As I TOKEN_PAGE instead TOKEN_user are: -> OAuthException: (#100) One and only one of params 'tab' or 'app_id' must be provided

Comment: Can you check what data's actually being passed to Facebook? POST `/PAGE_ID/tabs?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_PAGE&app_id=APP_ID` has worked for me many times so this should be OK

Comment: Does this example work? https://github.com/arsduo/koala/issues/63 - i've never used koala so i'm not sure if that's directly applicable to the current version but is an example of using the page access token

Comment: @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@token.access_token)
      @graph.put_connections("me", "tabs", :app_id => "xxx") is work! ths

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me as well. And I think the reason is http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194192344040832/. Running this on over Graph API Explorer gives the same result.

But I did using the following way

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new("user_access_token")
@newgraph=Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new("page_access_token")
@newgraph.put_connections("me","tabs", {:app_id => 'your_app_id'})
```

You basically make a graph object with the page access token and then run the put_connections method.